# Do a request Focus on edittexts created programaticcaly

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

I create some edittexts with a hashmap depending on a value given by the user. I can't do it in the xml because they doesn't exist before.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    layoutValueClassic.addView(edittextStatsList.get(i));
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setEms(2);
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_value);

    //FOCUS SUR L'EDITTEXT SUIVANT SAUF SI C'EST LE DERNIER
    edittextStatsList.get(i).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT && i < n - 1) {
                edittextStatsList.get(i + 1).requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

 }
```

As you can see, I put a requestfocus for each edittext on the next (i+1). But it doesn't work. I can't do "next" when I am in the edittext, I can just do "OK" and the focus disappears.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `IME OPTIONS` for each `edittext` in the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
...
edittextStatsList.get(i).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
....
}
```